# Any suggestions to find the approximated values without using for-loop?

Tags: matlab, math, vectorization

I have defined a vector `[0.11,1,3,4.5,7]`. I also has a function `f` which have the values `[f(0.11),f(1),f(3),f(4.5),f(7)]`. At the same time, I have another vector which may not have fixed length. Its value and length are determined by user. For simplicity, let assume the vector to `[4,4.5,5,6]`. I would like to do as follow in programming:

Obtain approximated values `f(4), f(4.5), f(5) and f(6)` from the given data input using linear approximation.

I understand that I can use for-loop to solve the problem; but I wonder if for-loop is necessary. Could someone think of a method without using for-loop?

Comment: Can't you just use `f` to evaluate `[4, 4.5, 5, 6]`? If you wrote `f` yourself, could it accept a vector input?

Comment: You can assume that I know what f is, e.g. f=t.^2 if you like. I can compute f([4,4.5,5,6])

Answer (score 5):

We can do it this way:

1. We can do it avoiding for-loop (and any other loops too :) ):

   ```
   x = [0.11 1 3 4.5 7]'
   f_values = [1 5 3 15 0]'
   xnew = [4 4.5 5 6]'
   fnew = interp1q(x,f_values,xnew)
   ```
2. But there is second interesting way: to fit your data. Matlab has strong fitting tool. 
   [For example this one](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/interactive-fitting.html). If you fit it you take function like this:
   `myf = @(x) here+some+formula`. So you can get any value of `f` for any `x` in anytime without any additional calculation.
3. If you know real value of `f` just create an anonymous function:

   ```
   f = @(x) x.^2
   ```

   And now you can just put your `[4,4.5,5,6]` values and get result:

   ```
   xnew = [4 4.4 5 6]
   result = f(xnew)
   ```